# Prove the following identity $\sum_{i=1}^na_i(x-b_i)^2+cx$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

Now I'm unsure whether 'prove' is better than 'show in this case, though I wished to understand how the complete formula for this identity is done? I cannot seem to figure out how the transitions is made, for example:

$\sum_{i=1}^na_i(x-b_i)^2+cx = \left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)\left(x-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i-c/2}{\sum_{i=1}^n} \right)^2+\sum_{i=1}^na_i\left(b_i-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i}{\sum_{i=1}^na_i} \right)^2+\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^{-1}\left[c\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i-c^2/4 \right]$

I know that the quadratic formula can be put into:

$x^2+bx+c=(x+\frac{b}{2})^2+(c−\frac{b^2}{4})$

I can see a similar structure though I would really appreciate some guidance on how to derive the form of complete the square.

Comment: What is the identity?

Comment: @Paul I believe that it comes from the normal distribution. I'ts given on page 281 on Probability and Statistics by Degroot

Comment: An identity is of the form A = B. You have no = in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since we do not what is the identity, just expand the summation to get
$$x^2\sum_{i=1}^n a_i+ \left(c-2\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\right) x+\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2$$